# PDDL How to assign number for many predicates

Tags: pddl

I have tile based map, where agent needs to go from one tile to another, Some tiles have **(occupied pos-X-Y)** meaning that agent cant step on these tiles named pos-X-Y. This part works, but I need to make these tiles occupied only in certain turns. I tried to use action-cost and add a number to each **(occupied pos-X-Y)** like this: **(occupied pos-X-Y Z)** planning to compare the Z number with the current action-cost. But I couldnt even assign the number to the occupied tile.

How do I assign a number to these occupied tiles and how do I compare it with the action-cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (with help). Instead of using numbers I created many objects, I will call them turns, then I set that, turn 2 is always after turn 1, turn 3 is always after turn 2 etc. and I added these turns as the letter z in "(occupied pos-X-Y Z)". And when actor moved I just changed his turn to the next number based on the rule I created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `functions` [Numeric Fluents](https://planning.wiki/ref/pddl21/domain#numeric-fluents) ?

Your `move` action can increase a "turn" function.

A `(forbidden_turn ?t - tile)` function can be affected with an integer value, then you can use it in a precondition. But this requires your planner to support negative preconditions.

Otherwise, you can use a `allowed turn` function.

Comment: yeah I used numeric fluents but the solver just skipped them entirely.

Comment: Which solver are you using ?
Can you share your PDDL domain and problem ?